# How to read N bytes from a file continuously untill the EOF

Tags: c++, base64, bit-manipulation

I am trying a wave to base 64 converter program.

I am trying this following code snippet:

```
    vector<char> in(3);
    std::string out = "abcd";         //four letter garbage value as initializer
    ifstream file_ptr(filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);

    unsigned int threebytes = 0;
    //Apply the Base 64 encoding algorithm
    do {
        threebytes = (unsigned int) file_ptr.rdbuf()->sgetn(&in[0], 3);
        if (threebytes > 0) {
            EncodeBlock(in, out, (int)threebytes);  //Apply conversion algorithm to convert 3 bytes into 4
            outbuff = outbuff + out;                //Append the 4 bytes got from above step to the output
        }
    } while (threebytes == in.size());

    file_ptr.close();
```

In encode block where the Base64 encoding algorithm is written

```
void EncodeBlock(const std::vector<char>& in, std::string& out, int len) {
    using namespace std;
    cb64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    out[0] = cb64[(int) (in[0] >> 2)];
    out[1] = cb64[(int) (((in[0] << 6) >> 2) | (in[1] >> 4))];
    out[2] = (len > 1) ?
             cb64[(int) (((in[1] << 4) >> 2) | (in[2] >> 6))] :
             '=';
    out[3] = (len > 2) ?
             cb64[(int) ((in[2] << 2) >> 2)] :
             '=';

}
```

The `cb64` is a 64 length long string but the index generated by bit manipulation sometimes fall out of range (0 to 63).

***Why!!!***

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to see, what is the value, that is out of range?

Comment: Are you talking about bits or bytes?

Comment: `using namespace std;` doesn't even save your `EncodeBlock` function a single byte. [Why are you doing that?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

Comment: @Bart Isn't in[0] or in[1] 8 bits? that is 1 byte!

Comment: @L.F. that is redundant. please ignore

Comment: @RC0993 it is, I now understand you are trying to shift the index based on the in vector.

Comment: You should use a stream of unsigned char to avoid sign duplication in the right shift.

Comment: @AlainMerigotDo you mean `vector<unsigned char> in(3)` ?

Comment: Yes. Or cast to unsigned what you read before right shifting.

Comment: Remember that everything is implicitly converted to `int` or `unsigned int` (depending on the signedness of `char`) before shifting. `(255 << 6) >> 2` is 4080; `(-1 << 6) >> 2` is -16.

Comment: @molbdnilo I am realising now that `(255 << 6) >> 2 is 4080` is indeed happening, but I am not sure how to make it `(255 << 6) >> 2 = 63`

Comment: Just mask with 0x3f before using as an index.

Comment: Read about how to mask out specific bits in your favourite bit-manipulation literature.

Comment: For a good book on bit-twiddling, Hacker's Delight by Henry S. Warren, Jr. is a treasure trove.

Comment: Hey Thanks, Everyone for your inputs. the bit manipulation worked. Finally I had masked it like this `out[0] = cb64[(unsigned int) ((in[0] >> 2) & 0x003f)];`

Comment: Are you still having issues *continuously reading* from the file? (per your question title)

Comment: No...! It is now resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution to this was to handle the bit manipulation correctly.

the `char` 8 bits are operated and then casted to `unsigned int` introduces 24 bits extra into it which needed to be set to `0`.

So,
`out[0] = cb64[(unsigned int) ((in[0] >> 2) & 0x003f)];`
`out[1] = cb64[(unsigned int) ((((in[0] << 6) >> 2) | (in[1] >> 4))) & 0x003f)];` .. and so on handles the masking